# Call function on most recently used object?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, undo

So, I'm writing a gui for Tic Tac Toe, using tkinter, and I'm trying to implement an "Undo" feature.

I have a class "Square" which is a subclass of canvas, with methods to draw a nought, cross or clear itself. The "Undo" function should work out which the most recently played square is, and call the clear method on it.

I have a global list of all moves, called "notation", so if I were able to call the clear function on the object returned by notation.pop(), this should work.

Is this a reasonable way of implementing this, and how do I?

Below is my code, and my current "Undo" button, which is hard coded to only ever undo C, the central Square.

```
import tkinter as tk

# notation is a list containing all moves made
notation = []

# This class defines a Square, just a clickable canvas which shows a nought or cross when clicked
class Square(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, name, master=None, width=None, height=None):
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.tic)
        self.bind("<Button-2>", self.tac)
        self.free=True
        self.name=name


    def tic(self, event):
        """"This will draw a cross on the selected Square."""
        if self.free:
            self.create_line(30, 30, 170, 170)
            self.create_line(30, 170, 170, 30)
            self.free = False
            global notation
            notation.append(self.name)
            print(notation)

    def tac(self, event):
        """"This will draw a nought on the selected Square."""
        if self.free:
            self.create_oval(30, 30, 170, 170)
            self.free = False
            global notation
            notation.append(self.name)
            print(notation)

    def clear(self):
        """"This will clear the selected Square."""
        if not self.free:
            self.delete("all")
            self.free = True
            global notation
            notation.pop()
            print(notation)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")

NW = Square("NW", master=root, width=200, height=200)
NW.grid(row=0, column=0)

N = Square("N", master=root, width=200, height=200)
N.grid(row=0, column=1)

NE = Square("NE", master=root, width=200, height=200)
NE.grid(row=0, column=2)

W = Square("W", master=root, width=200, height=200)
W.grid(row=1, column=0)

C = Square("C", master=root, width=200, height=200)
C.grid(row=1, column=1)

E = Square("E", master=root, width=200, height=200)
E.grid(row=1, column=2)

SW = Square("SW", master=root, width=200, height=200)
SW.grid(row=2, column=0)

S = Square("S", master=root, width=200, height=200)
S.grid(row=2, column=1)

SE = Square("SE", master=root, width=200, height=200)
SE.grid(row=2, column=2)

# Creating File Menu
menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

fileMenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=lambda: C.clear())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I realise that as it stands, the undo logic doesn't quite make sense, as it's entirely possible for C to not be the last item in notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sorta the right idea. What you need to do is add the entire instance to the notation list, and then when you pop the last one off you can call it's clear method:

```
def tac(self, event):
        notation.append(self) # add this instance to the list

...
fileMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=lambda: notation.pop().clear())
```

And get rid of the `pop` in the clear method.

Edit: As you probably know, global variables are bad. In a situation like this we use class variables, which are basically instance variables that are accessible by all the instances of the class. A class variable is defined outside of a method and without a "self." prefix, however you need to use the classname or "self" to access it (eg in your case you access it with `self.notaion` from inside the class or `Square.notation` from outside). We would also use class methods to manipulate them. See if you can understand this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Square(tk.Canvas):
    notation = [] # this is a class variable

    def __init__(self, name, master=None, width=None, height=None):
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.tic)
        self.bind("<Button-2>", self.tac)
        self.free=True
        self.name=name

    def tic(self, event):
        """"This will draw a cross on the selected Square."""
        if self.free:
            self.create_line(30, 30, 170, 170)
            self.create_line(30, 170, 170, 30)
            self.free = False
            self.notation.append(self)
            self.print()

    def tac(self, event):
        """"This will draw a nought on the selected Square."""
        if self.free:
            self.create_oval(30, 30, 170, 170)
            self.free = False
            self.notation.append(self)
            self.print()

    def clear(self):
        """"This will clear the selected Square."""
        if not self.free:
            self.delete("all")
            self.free = True
            self.print()

    @classmethod
    def undo(cls):
        cls.notation.pop().clear()

    @classmethod
    def print(cls):
        print('History:', *[s.name for s in cls.notation])

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
for i, name in enumerate('NW N NE W C E SW S SE'.split()):
    s = Square(name, master=root, width=200, height=200)
    row, column = divmod(i, 3)
    s.grid(row=row, column=column)

# Creating File Menu
menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

fileMenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=Square.undo)

root.mainloop()
```

I also got rid of your repetition. Remember DRY ... if you are copy/pasting code you are doing the computer's job.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does work. The only problem is, now I'll need a second global list for easy to read moves that I keep in sync, which is annoying, but not a big deal.

Comment: No you don't. You can use the same list. For instance `print([s.name for s in notation])`.

Comment: Super, that seems really obvious now. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you a better way to write this.

Comment: Thanks. I actually hated the nine entries per square, I just did it earlier today when I was excited to get this to work, and hadn't gotten round to coming up with a better way yet, so I really appreciate this. It's a bit late, but I'll have a look at the class variable and classmethod stuff tomorrow.